# Burninate "cheap"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Currently there are 17 questions (including [**this gem**](https://serverfault.com/questions/533780/may-someone-assist-with-my-benefits-and-cons-of-social-networking)) which are mostly shopping related, and I would wager that any new questions created on that tag would be similar.  I move that we torch [cheap](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cheap)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are no longer any questions tagged [cheap](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cheap).
The tag itself will be eaten by grues shortly.

Comment: Righteous.  Happy Monday.

Comment: Destroying bad tags ***ALMOST*** makes up for the fact that Mondays still exist.